# Deciding between computer, laptop or tablet-hybrid

Tags: laptop, gaming, desktop, tablet

i'm not using all my computer hardware regularly anymore and want to make a change.
Currently i have:

1. 1 stationary computer capable of running recent games
2. 1 mini tv
   computer which stutters badly and i want to get rid of
3. 1 remote
   virtual server running linux
4. a router with a built-in NAS capability onto which i can plug-in hard drives

My idea was to use the stationary computer for gaming and the mini computer for Netflix and stuff at the TV.
However my personal situation has changed to a level where i rarely use my stationary computer anymore. After work i mostly use the mini computer. This has resulted in me having two "divergent" workspaces.
Additionally, most weekends i'm away and don't use either computer, although i wish i had a mobile computer with me. Other weekends i have time for gaming, although it's a few hours tops.
So these are my new requirements:

1. Be mobile enough to take with me on weekends
2. Capable of playing games at Full HD res. (Skyrim Special Edition as a benchmark)
3. Capable of programming/compilation (Python and Go mostly) and running office software
4. Have some sort of cable docking solution so i can easily move it from TV to home office and also take it with me on weekends without having to remove 5 different cables each time

My idea was to trade both computers for either a laptop or a very powerful tablet (if that exists). My storage hard drive would go onto my router NAS and thereby be accessible from home or away. I also thought of using my virtual server as an additional workspace, but i'm not sure if i would be using it regularly (since it requires good internet). I want to parallel install Ubuntu and Windows.

**What would you buy if you were me? My budget is around $1500 (Euros, actually).**

I looked at the Razer Blade, which seems to fulfil my requirements but is above what i want to spend and maybe even overpowered for the few times i'm actually gaming.
Another option is just to replace the mini computer with a budget tablet or laptop, but then i'd still have two workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work [MSI 17.3" GE72VR Apache Pro-009](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834154299&ignorebbr=1)

```
GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB (VR Ready)
Intel Core i7 6700HQ (2.60 GHz)
16 GB Memory 1 TB HDD 256 GB SSD
17.3" Full HD 1920 x 1080
16.49" x 11.02" x 1.14" 5.95 lbs.
DVD Super Multi
```

Recommended specs for Skyrim:SE

OS: Windows 7/8.1/10 (64-bit Version)

Processor: Intel i5-2400/AMD FX-8320

Memory: 8 GB RAM

Graphics: NVIDIA GTX 780 3GB /AMD R9 290 4GB

Storage: 12 GB available space

As far as using the system for programming/compilation:  I am using a lower end MSI gaming system, a GL62-6QF for C++, as well as building custom linux distributions in both virtual and native situations.

When it comes to Home Theater vs Home Office setup, I am not sure how you have things set up, but I am using a receiver with HDMI pass-thru to the TV, so all that is needed is one HDMI cable to the receiver input for both surround sound and visual output.  Am also using a full mechanical keyboard and wired mouse in place of the built in KB/touchpad.

System weighs in at 5.95Lbs (2.698875 Kilo), which I personally wouldn't consider too heavy in a backpack if moving somewhere on a weekend.

1,599USD   /   1,447.47Euro

Comment: Interesting. Although i'm not the biggest fan of 17" laptops, i will take a look at it. I just have to find a good price in Germany, it seems to be a bit more expensive here.

Comment: Hey, it could always be the new GT83 series, at something like 18.3" and 13Lbs+   Then again they pack dual 1080s in SLI....and run something around 4 to 5,000USD....I am surprised no one else has chimed in with suggestions though.

Comment: oh wait, i meant 17" is too large, not too small. Does the MSI contain the full versionof GTX 1060 or is it a "mobile" version with less computing power?

Comment: I was making a joke, it did not come across well, I meant that hey at least it isn't an 18" laptop lol, the dominator lineup, is a monstrosity....hardly a "laptop" more like a Lap Crusher.  As to the 1060 question.  Here is a gaming benchmark from [Techpowerup](https://www.techpowerup.com/reviews/MSI/GE72VR_Apache_Pro/9.html)  Note that they test at the same settings for desktop GPUs, so as to show what to expect from a gaming laptop as opposed to a desktop.